# Basic jest test on a 1 function file gets 0% coverage

Tags: jestjs

I have 2 files with 1 function in it. My test is just as simple, see below:

doc.js

```
export function createSynthId(doc) {
  const synthId = `${doc.attachmentId}-${doc.materialId}-${doc.fileName}-${doc.title}-${doc.materialURL}`;
  return synthId;
}
```

doc.test.js

```
import { createSynthId } from './doc';

describe('doc', () => {
  it('create synthetic id', () => {
    expect(createSynthId(global.doc)).toEqual('987654-123456-File Name.pptx-undefined-');
  });

  it('create synthetic id', () => {
    expect(createSynthId({})).toEqual('undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined-undefined');
  });
});
```

My second file is virtually the same, just a larger function. Both tests pass, but coverage is being reported at 0% for Statements, Functions, and Lines, but 100% for Branches. The coverage report is showing all the lines red as well.

[image]

We have many similar files and they all work. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

I added a temp function to `doc.js`

```
export const makeTestsHappy = () => {
  console.log(CONFIG);
};
```

adding to `doc.test.js`

```
  it('does more', () => {
    makeTestsHappy();
  });
```

and when I try to test that, I get the error `TypeError: (0 , _doc.makeTestsHappy) is not a function`

Comment: did you imported that makeTestsHappy function? you can put logs inside `createSynthId` to check if it is being called while the tests are executed

Comment: i did both of those, and i was not seeing the logs run. However, see the answer below. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dummy over here was mocking the file I was testing. I forgot to `jest.unmock('/doc')` It immediately started working when I unlocked. Thanks all for your patience :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your test file from `doc.test.js` to `doc.spec.js`. You are using the BDD syntax and the correct name should include `spec`.

Comment: no luck, changing to spec didn't do anything. Also, my 200+ other tests all use `.test.js` just fine.